# How do we evaluate $\int \sec x^4 dx$?

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

**Question**

$$\int \sec \left(x^4\right) dx$$

---

Seriously, how do we do this?

I know that there is no elementary function who's derivative is $\sec x^4$. But still how can we do this?

**Or Perhaps even better:**

> $$\int \sec (x^n) dx$$
>
> where $n>1$

Comment: If there is no elementary function then you just need to do numerics instead. You can give this thing a name if you want, but it doesn't make the numerical process any easier.

Comment: @Ian is there atleast a closed form in terms of non-elementary functions?

Comment: Which ones? It is not generally agreed which non-elementary functions are available to use.

Comment: @Ian what do you mean by generally not agreed?

Comment: There are many, many non-elementary functions. Some of them come up more frequently, and we cook up numerical tools for computing them accurately; those ones tend to get named and studied at some length. These include things like the Gamma function, the Bessel functions, the elliptic integrals, and so on. When you ask "can this antiderivative be expressed in terms of non-elementary functions", the simple answer is "yes: you just did".

Comment: But this is usually not the answer you want, which means that to give a representation in terms of non-elementary functions, you must specify which non-elementary functions are available to use in the representation.

Comment: @Ian Oh you mean like how we use $Si (x)$? , etc? Yes please not like that. However I am fond of Gamma , Beta functions so its okay to write in terms of those type.

Comment: @Ian I have no idea why I am getting answering addressing a different problem. And no idea why people r down voting this question when I haven't down voted any of these irrelevant answers :/

Comment: @M.S.E  Thanks. I have deleted my answer. The integral you are asking does not seem to have elementary representations. I also checked Tables of Integrals, Series, and Products by Gradshteyn and Ryzhik which some consider as the bible for such things.

Comment: @Shailesh No problem. Thank you for the supportive effort :) Cheers!

Comment: I tried out various integrals of $\sec^n x$ on the online integral calculator, and noticed no immediate pattern. http://www.integral-calculator.com/

Comment: @AdamHrankowski I am trying to integrate $\sec x^n$

Comment: Whooooah! It's waaaaaay to early for me. Sorry!

Comment: I tried *that* and it came back with "I'm sorry Dave, I'm afraid I can't do that."

Comment: @AdamHrankowski hehe :)

Comment: You tagged this with 'definite integrals'; is this incorrect, or what are the integration bounds?

Comment: @CalvinKhor sorry its incorrect, let me fix it